# Using kue-scheduler with ParseServer on Heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, redis, kue

In running kue-scheduler on heroku with the heroku redis plugin, while I can get kue jobs to work, it seems that kue-scheduler is requiring certain configuration of redis not allowed for in the heroku redis environment. Has anyone had success running kue-scheduler in an Heroku environment. Here is the start of my index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var kue = require('kue-scheduler')
var queue = kue.createQueue({redis:
        'redis://h:***************@ec2-**-19-83-130.compute-1.amazonaws.com:23539'
        });

var job = queue.create('test', {
    title: 'Hello world'
  , to: 'j@example.com'
  , template: 'welcome-email'
}).save( function(err){
   if( !err ) console.log( job.id );
});

job.log('$Job %s run', job.id);

queue.every('30 seconds', job);

queue.process('test', function(job, done){
  test_function(job.data.title, done);
});

function test_function(title, done) {
  console.log('Ran test function with title %s', title)
  // email send stuff...
  done();
}
```

And here is the error.

```
2016-07-21T00:46:26.445297+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:410
2016-07-21T00:46:26.445299+00:00 app[web.1]:             throw err;
2016-07-21T00:46:26.445300+00:00 app[web.1]:             ^
2016-07-21T00:46:26.445417+00:00 app[web.1]: ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'config'
2016-07-21T00:46:26.445419+00:00 app[web.1]:     at parseError (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:161:12)
2016-07-21T00:46:26.445420+00:00 app[web.1]:     at parseType (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:222:14)
2016-07-21T00:46:26.466188+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

The issue is that heroku redis doesn't allow config options on its redis infrastructure from what I can tell.

If someone has had success, grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: This issue specifically I was able to resolve via:

    `var Queue = kue.createQueue({
       redis: 'redis://x:xxxxxxxxxxx@ec2-50-19-83-130.compute-1.amazonaws.com:23539',
       skipConfig: true
    }
    );`

However, the recurring tasks don't seem to run.

Comment: Did you had to create `worker` dyno as well to get this whole setup working?

Comment: I think I've noticed the inconsistencies with the setup that you've in place with `skipConfig:true`. Can you please verify the behaviour as expected?

Answer (score 5):

managed to solve this by:

```
var queue = kue.createQueue(
                {redis: 'redis://xxxxxxxxxxxxx@ec2-50-19-83-130.compute-1.amazonaws.com:23539',
                 skipConfig: true
                });
```

Just need the `skipConfig` parameter

Comment: did you end up getting the recurring tasks to work? I have a similar setup, no errors, but no tasks are being run.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and was unable to get `kue-scheduler` working on `Heroku-Redis`. To solve, I instead used the Heroku Add-on `Redis Cloud`.

This allows you to set the required Redis flag `notify-keyspace-events` which isn't modifiable on the regular `Heroku-Redis` add-on. To set this flag:

1. Add Redis Cloud heroku add-on
2. Go to heroku settings page
3. Reveal Config Vars in Config Variables
4. Copy `REDISCLOUD_URL`, it should be something like `redis://rediscloud:PASSWORD@xxx.redislabs.com:PORT_NUMBER`
5. In terminal enter `redis-cli -h xxx.redislabs.com -p PORT_NUMBER -a PASSWORD` with variables from `REDISCLOUD_URL`
6. Once connected, enter `config set notify-keyspace-events Ex`
7. You can verify it is set correctly by entering config get notify-keyspace-events
8. Make sure to update your javascript code to point to your new `REDISCLOUD_URL` when calling `kue.createQueue()`

credit to @josephktcheung for their work though here: https://github.com/lykmapipo/kue-scheduler/issues/46